# passing data from child to grandparent

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to React and still learning.
I'm trying to pass data from child to grandparent. So far I reach to parent and I`m stuck.

Child component:

```
export class Child extends React.Component{
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state= {
      counterChild: 5
    }
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <span>Child: {this.state.counterChild}</span><br />
        <button onClick={this.props.data(this.state.counterChild)}>Click me</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Parent component:

```
export default class Parent extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state= {
      counterParent: 0
    }
  }

  updateParent(value) {
    return() => {
      this.setState({
        counterParent: value
      });
    }
  }

  componentWillMount(){
    this.props.data(this.state.counterParent) 
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        <span>Parent: {this.state.counterParent}</span>
        <Child data={this.updateParent.bind(this)}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

in child component i use a button
and here i guess i have to use componentWillMount in order to send to grandparent..but it does not reach

Grandparent component:

```
export default class Grandparent extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      counterGrandparent: 0
    }
  }

  updateGrandparent(value){
    return() => {
      this.setState({
        counterGrandparent: value
      });
    }
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        <span>Grandparent: {this.state.counterGrandparent}</span>
        <Parent data={this.updateGrandparent.bind(this)}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

What did I do wrong here?

Answer (score 12):

As you may have figured out, data is passed *down* the component tree in the form of props, and *up* in the form of prop callback functions. When something happens in a child, you call the callback to inform the parent. The parent then updates its state and passes the new state to the child as a prop.

In your case, you have three nested components, each with their own state. Typically, only a parent "container" component will have state, and child components will be stateless. So let's remove the state from the Child and Parent components. The Child component interacts with the user with a button, so whenever the button is pushed, the event handler is called and the data flows up the tree using callbacks. I added some borders and padding to make the nesting clear:

[image: nested counter]

Part of the problem lies in the `onClick` handler on your button. Event handlers should be function references, but you have used a function *call*. So your child might be like below. Note the `counter` prop that receives the current state, and the `updateParent` prop that allows the Child to update the Parent.

```
import React from 'react';

const boxStyle = {
    border: '1px solid red',
    padding: '5px'
};

export class ChildWithButton extends React.Component {
    handleClick(event) {
        this.props.updateParent(this.props.counter + 1);
    }
    render() {
        return(
            <div style={boxStyle}>
                <div>Child: {this.props.counter}</div>
                <button onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}>
                    Add 1
                </button>
            </div>
          );
    }
}
```

The Parent component passes the current state down in the `counter` prop, and lets the Child component change the state by calling the `updateParent` callback that it received as a prop:

```
export class Parent extends React.Component{
    updateParent(value) {
        this.props.updateGrandparent(value);
    }
    render() {
        return(
            <div style={boxStyle}>
                <div>Parent: {this.props.counter}</div>
                <ChildWithButton
                    counter={this.props.counter}
                    updateParent={this.updateParent.bind(this)} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

The Grandparent component holds the state, passing it down to the Parent in `counter` and allowing it to update it with `updateGrandparent`. It should be noted that Grandparent has no knowledge of Child, only of Parent.

```
export default class Grandparent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {counter: 5};
    }
    updateGrandparent(value){
        this.setState({counter: value});
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div style={boxStyle}>
                <div>Grandparent: {this.state.counter}</div>
                <Parent
                    counter={this.state.counter}
                    updateGrandparent={this.updateGrandparent.bind(this)} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

You should avoid using `componentWillMount` as it will be [removed](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/03/27/update-on-async-rendering.html) in a future version of React.

You should also name the function you pass down in props something other than `data`. Function names are typically verbs.

There was more than one thing wrong with your code, so I hope this answers your question.

Comment: @usuario128216 Although it is an old entrance, you have saved me! Many thanks